# How are network interface statistics generated?

Tags: linux, network-interface

I was wondering how are the network interface statistics generated?
Could someone point me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system kernel has to handle every network packet that flows in and out of the system and so it is a simple matter for the kernel to maintain counters and provide an API for other programs to display the statistics the kernel maintains.

Comment: yes and for example if i have now out traffic 80GiB then it is the overall traffic from the system installation or the traffic measured from the last reboot?

Comment: @rsz Since last reboot almost certainly for Unix-ish systems.  I have no idea about Windows.